# Are ekaconjugated polymers used as dielectrics? If not, why so?

Tags: energy, polymers, materials

So I came across an article called "Giant polarization in high polymers" and I was wondering if there was a reason why these types of polymers haven't found use in capacitors at this point.  This being ekaconjugated polymers which can store energy using nomadic polarization.  Perhaps the issue is with dielectric loss?  The paper also reports results at high pressures.  I've found surprisingly little on this concept in the last twenty years (with basic searches).

Comment: I'm certain we have members here who can address your query. That said, you might get more traction on Electrical Engineering SE if you don't get something satisfactory or complete, just a heads-up.

Comment: Well, I for one didn't know that eka-conjugation means "extended long-range electron orbital delocalization" in stuff like conductive polymers, much less whatever "nomadic polarization" is...

Comment: <ruling-out @Mithoron> on this one :)

Comment: If ekaconjugated polymers means conjugated polymers, there is work considering them in almost every electronics and optics scenario's. The broad class can be further divided. However, they can have very high dielectric but are prone to charge injection. I would resume that in many cases they aren't enough insulating. Exception and specific arrangement may differ, of course. But at the chemical physical level I think the answer is "they are too conducting". Also stability toward degradation is a rather general issue.